# Validate and Format Array Output Based on Another Array (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, filter, ecmascript-6

Hoping to find a more efficient way to handle the below problem than my current solution (which is included).

I have the following array describing a user:

```
const userFields = [
     {key: "name", value: "tyler"},
     {key: "location", value: "boston"},
     {key: "phone", value: "555-555-5555"},
     {key: "email", value: "tyler@test.com"}
 ]
```

and an array which outlines allowed primary fields (some required, some optional):

```
const primaryFields = [
    { key: "name", alias: ["nickname"], required: true },
    { key: "address", alias: ["location", "homebase"], required: true },
    { key: "age", alias: [], required: true },
    { key: "phone", alias: [], required: false },
    { key: "gender", alias: [], required: false }
 ]
```

Looking to validate the userFields array with the information provided in the primaryFields array and produce three possible outputs: primary fields (object), secondary fields (array), missing fields (array). Also, a couple caveats, 1. userFields should be recognized by either the key or alias and 2. the key for primary fields should be that of key used in primaryFields array (if alias used in userFields).

So the above should output:

```
{
     primary:{
        name: "tyler",
        address: "boston",
        phone: "555-555-5555"
    },
     secondary: [
        {key: "email", value: "tyler@test.com"}
     ],
     missing: ["age"]    
 }
```

Here is a gist that includes my solution:
https://gist.github.com/tilersmyth/26984866d7428c9b502ec8971d961997

The basic process is:

1. Loop through userFields to update keys based on PrimaryField keys (if alias used) and log those keys (to check required)
2. Check for required fields that are missing
3. Identify remaining userFields which will be pushed as secondary items

**Any insight into an approach that could be more efficient?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce to reduce an array to an object or an array

```js
const userFields = [
     {key: "name", value: "tyler"},
     {key: "location", value: "boston"},
     {key: "phone", value: "555-555-5555"},
     {key: "email", value: "tyler@test.com"}
 ];
 
 const primaryFields = [
    { key: "name", alias: ["nickname"], required: true },
    { key: "address", alias: ["location", "homebase"], required: true },
    { key: "age", alias: [], required: true },
    { key: "phone", alias: [], required: false },
    { key: "gender", alias: [], required: false }
 ];
 
const validate = (user, primary) => ({
  primary: user.reduce(
    (p, field) =>
      primary.find(f => field.key === f.key || f.alias.includes(field.key))
        ? { ...p, [field.key]: field.value }
        : p,
    {}
  ),
  secondary: user.reduce(
    (results, field) =>
      !primary.find(f => field.key === f.key || f.alias.includes(field.key))
        ? [ ...results, field ]
        : results,
    []
  ),
  missing: primary.reduce(
    (results, field) =>
      field.required && !user.find(f => f.key === field.key || field.alias.includes(f.key))
        ? [...results, field.key]
        : results,
    []
  )
});
 
 console.log(validate(userFields, primaryFields));
```